# NSDateから和暦で年数だけ書き出したい

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

oyという文字列の中にグレゴリオ暦での年数が入っています
例えばoyに"2015"と入っているとして下記のようなコードを書きました

```
var date_string: String  = "\(oy)"
println(oy)
var date_formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
date_formatter.locale     = NSLocale.currentLocale()
date_formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
var change_date:NSDate = date_formatter.dateFromString("\(oy)")!

println("\(change_date)")

let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)

func getYear()->Int {
    let myCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let myComponents = calendar!.components(.YearCalendarUnit, fromDate: change_date)
    let year = myComponents.year
    return year
}

tablesection.append("\(getYear())")

oy++
```

そうしたらiPhoneに設定された暦（今の設定は和暦になっています）に変換されるどころか4003と全く関係ない数字が表示されてしまいました
どうすれば正しく変換されますか？

Comment: 平成2015年を西暦に直すと4003年なので変換方向が逆です。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2015をiPhoneに設定されている和暦のカレンダーで変換しているためです。
2015は西暦なので、そこから`NSDate`にする場合は西暦を使う必要があります。

そして、その`NSDate`から和暦に変換する際には、和暦のカレンダーを設定します。

たとえば次のように元のコードを修正します。

```
var date_string: String  = "\(oy)"
println(oy)
var date_formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
date_formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
date_formatter.locale     = NSLocale.currentLocale()
date_formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
var change_date :NSDate = date_formatter.dateFromString("\(oy)")!

println("\(change_date)")

func getYear()->Int {
    let myCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierJapanese)
    let myComponents = myCalendar!.components(.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: change_date)
    let year = myComponents.year
    return year
}

println("\(getYear())")
```

Comment: kishikawaさんが返答してくれるとは思いませんでした
ありがとうございました